# Counting orders and grouping them, linq to sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table called Orders
the table has many rows but im only interested in two in particular.
I want to query the table so it returns the average ordered count of each product
i want to know what is the average count of the ordered products, but now in total but per productID instead.
How can this be done?

i tried this:

```
Dim ord = From e In db.Orders
          Group e By e.ProductID Into grp
          Select New With {.Id = e.ProductID, .Avg = grp.average}
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Dim ord = (db.Orders.GroupBy(Function(n) n.ProductID, Function(key, values) New With {.ID = key, .Avg = values.Average(Function(n) n.Amount)})).GetEnumerator

Comment: well my first comment is the actual solution to the problem, but since my rep is low i cant mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it but had to wait for rep up.

```
Dim ord = (db.Orders.GroupBy(Function(n) n.ProductID, Function(key, values) New With {.ID = key, .Avg = values.Average(Function(n) n.Amount)})).GetEnumerator
```